# Uncaught Object - Angular js

Tags: angularjs

Just started with Angular and trying to bind images.
This error shows up after page load in chrome.

'Uncaught Object - MINNER ASSET: 22

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/
angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function DemoController($scope) {
            $scope.images = [
                { "src": "Images/1.jpg" },
                { "src": "Images/2.jpg" }                
            ];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img src="{{image.src}}" />
     </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: use ng-src instead of src

Comment: reason to use ng-src and not src https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you miss var app = angular.module("DemoApp",[]);

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/
    angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module("DemoApp",[]);
      app.controller("DemoController",
            function DemoController($scope) {
                $scope.images = [
                    { "src": "Images/1.jpg" },
                    { "src": "Images/2.jpg" }                
                ];
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" />
         </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined DemoApp, you can skip the app name.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="DemoController">
```